# Best data structure to store for a grouping relation and support look

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap

I need to create a data structure to keep track of some grouping information. Assuming the elements are just strings. For instance, {'a', 'b', 'c'} is a group and {'e', 'f', 'g'} is another groups. I also need to support lookup by keys and keys are all strings. For now, I can think of using a map:

```
{a} -> {"a", "b", "c"}
{b} -> {"a", "b", "c"}

{e} -> {"e", "f", "g"}
{f} -> {"e", "f", "g"}
```

But in this case, I am duplicating lots of information in the map and the size will explode. Any other good data structure which is compact and also support fast lookup?

Comment: "*But in this case, I am duplicating lots of information in the map*" - how so? What is duplicated here? Are you concerned that an array / vector of 3 elements will introduce performance issues? You may always have a map of `std::shared_ptr`s as values to said arrays/vectors.

Comment: One question. Is key `a` called a because it's list of elements contains "a"? And is it the same case for "b" and "c"?

Comment: Why is this tagged [c++] ?   If you want a C++answer please show what you have tried so far.  You should read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: What constitutes a "good data structure" is determined by requirements, and your requirements are incomplete. If all you want is fast lookup of groups, you could map `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` to `1`; and `"e"`, `"f"` and `"g"` to `2`. (Since you put no requirements on the groups, all that needs to be stored for them are values that allow comparing for equality. Integers are convenient for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in this case, I am duplicating lots of information in the map and
>   the size will explode. Any other good data structure which is compact
>   and also support fast lookup?

Instead of mapping the elements directly to groups, you can introduce an additional level of indirection to do away with this duplication by mapping the elements, which are `std::string`s, to *group IDs*, which are indexes. Then, you can keep an `std::vector` of groups. You use the group IDs retrieved by the mapping to index this vector of groups.

As an example implementing this idea:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class GroupRelation {
   std::unordered_map<std::string, group_id_t> elem2group_id_;
   std::vector<std::unordered_set<std::string>> groups_;
public:
   using group_id_t = size_t;

   auto num_groups() const { groups_.size(); }

   auto add_group(std::unordered_set<std::string> group) {
      auto grp_id = groups_.size();
      for (auto const& elem: group)
         elem2group_id_[elem] = grp_id;

      groups_.push_back(std::move(group));
      return grp_id; // return group_id_t of just added group
   }

   // for checking whether or not an element is in a group
   bool is_in_group(const std::string& elem) const {
      auto it = elem2group_id_.find(elem); 
      return elem2group_id_.end() != it;
   }

   // returns the group ID where the element belongs
   group_id_t group_id(const std::string& elem) const {
      auto it = elem2group_id_.find(elem); 
      return it->second;
   }

   const std::unordered_set<std::string>& group(group_id_t group_id) const {
      return groups_[group_id];
   }

   std::unordered_set<std::string>& group(group_id_t group_id) {
      return groups_[group_id];
   }
};
```

Retrieving the group ID from an element can be done in constant time on average.

An example of use:

```
auto main() -> int {
   GroupRelation grp_rel;

   grp_rel.add_group({"a", "b", "c"});   
   grp_rel.add_group({"e", "f", "g"});

   for (auto const& elem: grp_rel.group(0))
      std::cout << elem << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';

   for (auto const& elem: grp_rel.group(1))
      std::cout << elem << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';

}
```

My output:

```
b c a 
g f e
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have one fast data-structure you have to use it wisely.
if you want two make keys of 3 different string (s1,s2,s3) do this

Adding key,value in map 
     make a new string `s1+"_"+s2+"_"+s3`
use this as key

While Retrieving value from map
     make a new string `s1+"_"+s2+"_"+s3`
use this as key

UnderScore here is doing all the work.

This is fast enough too.